# Get products which had a price update last week

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is my table History:

```
productnr    price     changedate
1001           5         06.05.2020
1001           9         01.10.2021
1001           10        08.10.2021
1002           6         01.04.2021
1002           7         14.05.2021
1002           14        07.10.2021
```

I need to have every product which its price change last week AND the difference between last price and new price is more than 15 percent.

**The desired result:**

```
productnr     newprice    oldprice       last_changedate    secondlast_changedate 
1002          14            7                07.10.2021      14.05.2021
```

With this SQL query I have all products which their price changed last week :

```
Select *
from history
where TO_CHAR(changedate, 'iw') = TO_CHAR(next_day(trunc(sysdate+2), 'MONDAY') - 14, 'iw')
      and changedate > sysdate - 14
```

But I have no idea how can reach the desired result.

Comment: Select *
from history
where TO_CHAR(changedate, 'iw') = TO_CHAR(next_day(trunc(sysdate+2), 'MONDAY') - 14, 'iw')
      and changedate > sysdate - 14
     AND NEWPRICE>1.15*OLDPRICE

Comment: You did not understand my question, my friend. OLD and NEW are in DESIRED RESULT. I don't have it yet.

Comment: why 1001 - 9 - 5 - 6.5.2020 - 1.10.2021 is not in desired result ?

Comment: The change did not happen last week.

Comment: you mean : last week starts from monday ? (04.10.2021)

Comment: Yes. It is so in europe .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytic functions to find the previous values:

If you want to compare the latest `productnr` to the previous:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT h.*,
         LEAD(price     ) OVER (PARTITION BY productnr ORDER BY changedate DESC) AS oldprice,
         LEAD(changedate) OVER (PARTITION BY productnr ORDER BY changedate DESC) AS oldchangedate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productnr ORDER BY changedate DESC) AS rn
  FROM   history h
  WHERE  changedate > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY
)
WHERE  (price < oldprice * (1 - 0.15) OR price > oldprice * (1 + 0.15))
AND    rn = 1;
```

or, if you want to compare the first `price` per `productnr` this week to the last `price` last week:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT h.*,
         LEAD(price     ) OVER (PARTITION BY productnr ORDER BY changedate DESC) AS oldprice,
         LEAD(changedate) OVER (PARTITION BY productnr ORDER BY changedate DESC) AS oldchangedate
  FROM   history h
  WHERE  changedate >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY
  AND    changedate <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY
)
WHERE  (price < oldprice * (1 - 0.15) OR price > oldprice * (1 + 0.15))
AND    changedate    >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
AND    oldchangedate <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW');
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But "changedate > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY" didn't give the right week. I used mine.

Comment: @TimLer It looks like you just want to use `SYSDATE + 2` rather than `SYSDATE` in my queries.